# Adjusting the width of a block to cross a column border

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am facing a slight esthetic problem with a block. Originally my slide is divided in two columns of 0.6\linewidth and 0.4\linewidth. In the first column, there is two images next to each other with below some formula and below the problematic block. On the second column, there is just two images on top of each other with a slight caption below. The block is taking two lines and thus don't fit into the slide, as seen below.

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[pdf,10pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The aerodynamic model of \citet{Sane2002}}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.6\linewidth}
            \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Pictures/Chapter1/Wingview_Robofly}}
                    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Pictures/Chapter1/Polar_Curve}}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
                \begin{align}
            {\color{red}F_{aero}}= & {\color{green}F_{trans}}+{\color{cyan}F_{added}}+{\color{violet}F_{rot}}+(F_{wc})\\
            \onslide<4->{
            \text{with} &\quad\scriptstyle\color{green}F_{trans} = \frac{\rho SU_{t}^2\hat{r_2}^2(S)}{2}\left[C_{L}^2\left(\alpha\right)+C_{D}^2\left(\alpha\right)\right]^{1/2}\nonumber\\
            & \quad\scriptstyle\color{cyan}F_{added} = \rho\frac{\pi}{4}R^2\bar{c}^2\left(\ddot{\phi}\sin\alpha+\dot{\phi}\dot{\alpha}\cos\alpha\right)\int_0^1 \! \hat{r}\hat{c}^2\left(\hat{r}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\hat{r}\nonumber\\
            & \scriptstyle\color{cyan}\phantom{\quad\scriptstyle\color{cyan}F_{added} =}  - \ddot{\alpha}\rho\frac{\pi}{16}\bar{c}^3R\int_0^1 \! \hat{c}^2\left(\hat{r}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\hat{r}\nonumber\\
            & \quad\scriptstyle\color{violet}F_{rot} = C_{rot,exp}\rho U_{t}\dot{\alpha}\bar{c}^2R\int_0^1 \! \hat{r}\hat{c}^2\left(\hat{r}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\hat{r}}\nonumber
                \end{align}
                \vspace*{-.75cm}
                \begin{block}{}\setbeamertemplate{itemize  item}[triangle]
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Not compatible at first sight with a flexible wing
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.4\linewidth}
            \vspace*{-0.625cm}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=1.1\columnwidth]{Pictures/Chapter1/Advanced_Rotation_Forces}\\
                \includegraphics[width=.6\columnwidth]{Pictures/Chapter1/Advanced_Rotation_Motion}
            \end{center}
            \vspace*{-0.75cm}
            \begin{flushright}
                {\fontsize{4pt}{4.8pt}\selectfont Images: \citet{Dickinson1999} and \citet{Sane2002}}
            \end{flushright}
        \end{column}    
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So that everything fit into one slide, I want to modify locally the block width so that it can go beyond the column border and the text fit on a single line.

Comment: If all of that is necessary, I would spend 5 slides for this.

Comment: All of that is necessary to explain briefly the work of the guy and where I come in... I acknowledge that is crowed but everything fit together don't worry

Comment: It definitely does not fit together but anyway I can't convince you for your presentation.

Comment: @TazgerO: You can post a self-answer with your workaround if you like and then accept it yourself after a waiting period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I agree with the remark made. I found a quick fix even if not that nice.

I remove the block from the column environment and include it in a minipage environment that I shift slightly to the top by using a \vspace*.

Here is the code:

```
\visible<5->{
    \vspace*{-.75cm}
    \begin{minipage}{.675\linewidth}
        \begin{block}{}\setbeamertemplate{itemize  item}[triangle]
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Not compatible at first sight with a flexible wing
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}     
    \end{minipage}}
```

Not the niciest slide and solution but both are fulfilling their job quite fairly

Comment: As you've answered your own question, perhaps you should mark this as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with **percusse**; a slide shouldn't be that crowded. Anyway, instead of forcing the block to extend past the column border, I would propose you another solution: to locally reduce the font size and the value for `\leftmargini`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}% just for the example
\documentclass[pdf,10pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}% just for the example
\usepackage{natbib}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The aerodynamic model of \citet{Sane2002}}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.6\linewidth}
            \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=1cm]{Pictures/Chapter1/Wingview_Robofly}}
                    \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm,height=1cm]{Pictures/Chapter1/Polar_Curve}}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
                \begin{align}
            {\color{red}F_{aero}}= & {\color{green}F_{trans}}+{\color{cyan}F_{added}}+{\color{violet}F_{rot}}+(F_{wc})\\
            \onslide<4->{
            \text{with} &\quad\scriptstyle\color{green}F_{trans} = \frac{\rho SU_{t}^2\hat{r_2}^2(S)}{2}\left[C_{L}^2\left(\alpha\right)+C_{D}^2\left(\alpha\right)\right]^{1/2}\nonumber\\
            & \quad\scriptstyle\color{cyan}F_{added} = \rho\frac{\pi}{4}R^2\bar{c}^2\left(\ddot{\phi}\sin\alpha+\dot{\phi}\dot{\alpha}\cos\alpha\right)\int_0^1 \! \hat{r}\hat{c}^2\left(\hat{r}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\hat{r}\nonumber\\
            & \scriptstyle\color{cyan}\phantom{\quad\scriptstyle\color{cyan}F_{added} =}  - \ddot{\alpha}\rho\frac{\pi}{16}\bar{c}^3R\int_0^1 \! \hat{c}^2\left(\hat{r}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\hat{r}\nonumber\\
            & \quad\scriptstyle\color{violet}F_{rot} = C_{rot,exp}\rho U_{t}\dot{\alpha}\bar{c}^2R\int_0^1 \! \hat{r}\hat{c}^2\left(\hat{r}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\hat{r}}\nonumber
                \end{align}
                \vspace*{-.75cm}
                \begin{block}{}\setbeamertemplate{itemize  item}[triangle]
                {\setlength\leftmargini{10pt}%
                    \begin{itemize}\footnotesize
                        \item Not compatible at first sight with a flexible wing
                    \end{itemize}%
                }%                
                \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.4\linewidth}
            \vspace*{-0.625cm}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=1.1\columnwidth,height=1cm]{Pictures/Chapter1/Advanced_Rotation_Forces}\\
                \includegraphics[width=.6\columnwidth,height=1cm]{Pictures/Chapter1/Advanced_Rotation_Motion}
            \end{center}
            \vspace*{-0.75cm}
            \begin{flushright}
                {\fontsize{4pt}{4.8pt}\selectfont Images: \citet{Dickinson1999} and \citet{Sane2002}}
            \end{flushright}
        \end{column}    
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The line `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

I also used the `Warsaw` theme and the `natbib` package, and changed the height for the images, just for the example.

Comment: Ok I will try it. Just to be clear I know the slide is overcrowed...

Comment: Nevermind... I found a dummy solution to my problem. I just but the block in a minipage below the column environment and use a negative vspace* to replace it slightly up.
Thanks for your help folks, even if I choose another solution

Comment: @admin: How can I close this topic? Delete it?

Comment: @TazgerO why do you want to delete it? You can answer your own question with your solution.

Comment: My bad I totally forget that I could answer my own answer...